# Will iOS show popups to update to latest iOS?

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

We have developed a kiosk type of app with iOS 5.1.1. Now that iOS 6 is out I'm wondering if Apple will randomly show a popup to update to iOS 6? Obviously we don't want to update just yet and don't want our end users to see this pop up while using the kiosk.

If there will be a popup, is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: They will see the badge over the Settings icon which will lead them to the notification of the newer iOs version. What kind of popups do you mean ? I'm also interested what is the problem of end users updating their iOs version.

Comment: By popup i mean an Alert. This is a kiosk app distributed through the enterprise (not the app store). This app is not installed by end users. It's a controlled environment in the enterprise and we don't want to update because it was developed and tested with iOS 5.1.1. If an alert will never show up then it is ok.

Comment: Don't you have a corporate devices policy then not allowing the users to update the iOs version until it is tested ?

Comment: This device is opened to the public to use. We don't want anyone to come up to it and be prompted for an update. Regardless, this won't happen anyway.

Comment: Update: the popup will happen.

Comment: Have you determined a method for disabling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bad news, everyone (sorry, no full screen as there's a private app):[image]

Comment: This is something new that has not appeared before. Thanks for posting.

Comment: I can confirm this as we had the same thing show up on our end

Answer (score 3):

@ Leo. You are incorrect. I have my iPad open, and it just popped a blue alert window on my screen that said "Apple has released an update, blah blah, upgrade to iOS6".

So to confirm, it DOES show a pop up.

Comment: This must be something new. Thanks for letting me know. I removed my answer.

Answer (score 0):

We are in a similar situation with network-enabled iPads being used as kiosks.  We think that going into

Settings -> General -> Software Update -> Learn More

and then clicking the Done button on the modal will prevent the popup pictured in @A-Live's answer from happening again.  Unfortunately, this is a little hard to test as a real solution, but the iPads we have done this to have not shown the popup.